# Integrating $\int\frac{x^{9}}{1+x^{14}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How to solve
$$\int\frac{x^{9}}{1+x^{14}}\mathrm dx$$

I am trying this question by taking $x^{7} = u$ and then I am getting $7x^{6}\mathrm dx=\mathrm du$.
So, $x^{6}\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{7}\mathrm du$. Now $x^3$ will remain in the numerator and $x^3$ will be equal to $u^{\frac{3}{7}}$. So the final integral will be
$$\frac{1}{7}\int \frac{u^{\frac{3}{7}}}{1+u²}\mathrm du.$$

But how to approach further. Please help me out.

Comment: The integral does not look nice: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x%5E9%2F%281%2Bx%5E14%29

Comment: is it a indefinite integral? because if it's over $R$ (or any "symmetric" domain) is simply $0$ being the function odd. 
If you're just computing the antiderivative I am not sure it has a "nice" one

Comment: Are you sure the numerator isn't a typo for $x^6$? Then it would be a much cleaner result and more likely to be posed as a problem for students

Comment: I don't think you should spend your time on this. As @MartinR confirmed with Wolframalpha, the closed form seems horrible... If you want to compute in some bounds which yields nice result, fine!